# Gradle finds POM for dependency but not JAR

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-management, nexus, sonatype

We are hosting a local maven repository in Sonatype Nexus, in order to share our own jars across projects. We are having an issue with one jar in particular, where Gradle is able to find and download the POM, but not the JAR from Nexus. 
The error given in Gradle is simply:

Could not resolve: com.qf:qf-etl_2.11:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

We have not this problem with any other jar held in Nexus. There is one possibly notable difference between this jar, and other jars we are hosting, which is that this jar depends on another jar which is also held in our locally hosted maven repository.

We are using Gradle 2.14, and Nexus 3.0.1-01 (ESS)

All help and ideas are appreciated, and please let me know what additional information I need to provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POM was downloading without the JAR, because the JAR depended on two unmanaged (3rd party) JARs. The solution that I followed was to upload the third party JARs into Nexus as well, so that these could be found, guided by [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340057/publishing-custom-artifact-built-from-task-in-gradle)

Note that gradle:eclipse was not reporting missing dependencies, even though it would normally do this.